# previous greatest palindrome numbers before a given palindrome number

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

The Question is:
You are given a number 'N' in the form of a string 'S', which is a palindrome. You need to find the greatest number strictly less than 'N' which is also a palindrome.

I tried to solve this question but is giving wrong answer for some test cases. can anyone help me to correct my code.
Below is my code:

```
string nextSmallerPalindrome(string &s)
{
    int n = s.length();
    string ans = "";
    
    if(n == 1)
    {
        s[0]--;
        return s;
    }
    
    if(s == "11")
    {
        return "9";
    }
    
   // For Handling odd cases
    if(n % 2 != 0)
    {
        int idx = n / 2;
        int diff = 0;
        
        if(s[idx] == '0')
        {
            s[idx] = '9';
            diff = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            s[idx]--;
        }
        
        idx--;
        
        while(idx >= 0 && diff == 1)
        {
            if(s[idx] == '0')
            {
                s[idx] = '9';
                idx--;
            }
            else
            {
                s[idx]--;
                diff = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        int i = 0;
        while(i < n && s[i] == '0')
        {
            i++;
        }
        
        for(; i < n; i++)
        {
            ans = ans + s[i];
        }
        
        int new_n = ans.length();
        
        int j = 0;
        int k = new_n - 1;
        
        while(j < k)
        {
            if(ans[j] == ans[k])
            {
                j++;
                k--;
            }
            else
            {
                ans[k] = ans[j];
                j++;
                k--;
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
    else                             // For handling even cases
    {
        int idx = n / 2 - 1;
        int diff = 0;
        
        if(s[idx] == '0')
        {
            s[idx] = '9';
            diff = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            s[idx]--;
        }
        
        idx--;
        
        while(idx >= 0 && diff == 1)
        {
            if(s[idx] == '0')
            {
                s[idx] = '9';
                idx--;
            }
            else
            {
                s[idx]--;
                diff = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        int i = 0;
        while(i < n && s[i] == '0')   // For ignoring Zeros from front of the string
        {
            i++;
        }
        
        for(; i < n; i++)     //storing all the string s in new string ans after ignoring front 0
        {
            ans = ans + s[i];
        }
        
        int new_n = ans.length();
        
        int j = 0;
        int k = new_n - 1;
        
        while(j < k)                // checking and changing the last half into first half
        {
            if(ans[j] == ans[k])
            {
                j++;
                k--;
            }
            else
            {
                ans[k] = ans[j];
                j++;
                k--;
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Input Format:
The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.

The first and the only line of each test case contains a string 'S', denoting the number whose next smaller palindrome is to be found.

Test Case:

```
19
7
77
101
1001
1221
144441
3444444443
57855875
10000001
11
1
111
101
1001
11011
1110111
1190911
20002
10011001
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example test case where the answer is wrong?

Comment: i have an example test case , let me edit and put it there

Comment: I don't think your code gets all 19 of those wrong, does it? At first glance the only wrong one is 10000001 -> 9990999 which should be 9999999 but I haven't thought about them all carefully.

Comment: no all the test cases are not wrong but few of them are getting wrong. but i am unable to find error in my code. plz help me to fix this error.

Comment: Is 7 supposed to return 6 or 0?

Comment: I have solved this problem , there was minor error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but I will not fix the code. I will rather describe how I would solve it. If you like the idea, then you will have a very easy time doing it.

A palindrome has n digits. n may be pair or odd. The first n / 2 digits (rounded upwards) is a number. Get that number (cut down the digits in the second half) and subtract 1.

Look at the result and the number of its digits. If subtracting 1 decreases the number of digits of your half-number, then handle that accordingly. Should be easy if you have the right idea.

Comment: Actually , i have done the same thing that you have mentioned above. the whole logic is correct but there is some minor fault in my code.

Comment: @VishalKumar can you tell me which input is wrong, for instance? And what is returned?

Comment: hi, i have solved the problem , there was minor problem in my code.

Comment: @VishalKumar what was the problem and what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using the same expression for idx in even cases as odd cases works better.

(It still doesn't handle the case for `7`, though.)

Change this:

```
else                             // For handling even cases
{
    int idx = n / 2 - 1;
```

to this:

```
else                             // For handling even cases
{
    int idx = n / 2;
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here's a working code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
string nextSmallerPalindrome(string &s) {
    // Write your code here.
    string ans = s ; 
    if(s=="11"){
        return "9"; 
    }
    int c = 0 ; 
    if(s.size()%2==1){
        int k = s.size()/2 ;
        //string ans = s ; 
        while(k>=0){
            if(k==0 && ans[k]=='1' && ans.size()>1){
               // cout<<"hola\n"; 
                ans = ans.substr(1,ans.size()-2); 
                ans=ans+'9'; 
                break; 
            }
            if(ans[k]-'0'!=0){
                int temp = ans[k]-'0'; 
                temp-= 1 ; 
                ans[k] = (temp) +'0'; 
                ans[s.size()-1-k] = (temp) +'0'; 
                return ans; 
            }
            else{
                ans[k] = (9) +'0'; 
                ans[s.size()-1-k] = (9) +'0'; 
                k--; 
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        int k = s.size()/2 ;
        while(k>=0){
            if(k==0 && ans[k]=='1' && ans.size()>1){
                ans = ans.substr(1,ans.size()-2); 
                ans=ans+'9'; 
                break; 
            }
            if(ans[k]-'0'!=0){
                int temp = ans[k]-'0'; 
                temp-= 1 ; 
                ans[k] = (temp) +'0'; 
                ans[s.size()-1-k] = (temp) +'0'; 
                return ans ;
            }
            else{
                ans[k] = (9) +'0'; 
                ans[s.size()-1-k] = (9) +'0'; 
                if(c==0){
                    c++; 
                    k-=2; 
                }
                else k--; 
            }
        }
        
    }
    return ans ; 
    
}
```